# Deleting a full branch from n-ary tree

Tags: c, tree

I want to make a function capable of being able to delete a branch (or even the whole tree). The structure of the tree is the following:

```
typedef struct node {
    char data;
    struct node *child;
    struct node *sibling;
}*tree;
```

I made a function that is able to find a given data in the tree and then return the address of that node and then remove it. Lets say i want to delete the node that has `B` in the data, it should delete all it's children and the node itself, then i should be left with the following tree:

```
      R                        R     
      |                        |     
      B _ C _ D      -->>      C _ D              
      |       |                    | 
      E _ F   G                    G
```

I have the following function, but it's only useful for deleting the entire tree, if i use it for deleting branches i will be left with pointers pointing to memory that was already freed.

```
void delete_branch(tree node){
    if(node != NULL)
    {
        delete_branch(node->child);
        delete_branch(node->sibling);
        free(node);
    }
}
```

I know what the problem is, i just have to update the pointers so they point to correct positions again, but i can't wrap my head around how to do it with recursive functions involved. If more info is needed feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

considering you want to keep the sibling and not remove it

```
tree delete_branch(tree node) {
    tree new_child=NULL;
    if(node != NULL) {
        while(node->child!=NULL) { //the child will keep being replaced by his sibling
            node->child=delete_branch(node->child); // replace the child by his sibling until there is none
        }
        new_child=node->sibling; // before freeing the child keep his the pointer to his sibling 
        free(node);
    }
    return new_child; // the sibling will replace the deleted child in the parent reference
}
```

And when removing the child;

```
parent->child=delete(parent->child);
```

Comment: Now that should do the trick. Maybe i should add a pointer to parent to the structure to make it a bit easier.

Comment: What you mean by `parent->child=delete(parent->child);`? The deleted node can be either a direct child of someone or a sibling of his brother, so we may need handle different cases right?